# kubuntu upgrade 16.04.1 to 16.04.3, suspend not working

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, suspend

I'm running kubuntu on my dell xps 9350. After the upgrade to 16.04.3 the suspend is not working anymore.

Any suggestions/help about fixing this are much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Billy

//some info:

```
uname -r:
4.4.0-38-generic
```

Here is the part of the history log with the concerning update:

```
Start-Date: 2016-10-17  15:20:35
Upgrade: libnm-glib4:amd64 (1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.3), libavdevice-ffmpeg56:amd64 (7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2, 7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), update-manager-core:amd64 (1:16.04.3, 1:16.04.4), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-42.62, 4.4.0-43.63), libavutil-ffmpeg54:amd64 (7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2, 7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libsystemd0:amd64 (229-4ubuntu10, 229-4ubuntu11), libsystemd0:i386 (229-4ubuntu10, 229-4ubuntu11), libavfilter-ffmpeg5:amd64 (7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2, 7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libdbusmenu-glib4:amd64 (12.10.3+16.04.20160223.1-0ubuntu1, 16.04.1+16.04.20160927-0ubuntu1), libswresample-ffmpeg1:amd64 (7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2, 7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (53.0.2785.143-1, 54.0.2840.59-1), udev:amd64 (229-4ubuntu10, 229-4ubuntu11), libnm0:amd64 (1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.3), network-manager:amd64 (1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.3), libdbusmenu-gtk4:amd64 (12.10.3+16.04.20160223.1-0ubuntu1, 16.04.1+16.04.20160927-0ubuntu1), kbd:amd64 (1.15.5-1ubuntu4, 1.15.5-1ubuntu5), libudev1:amd64 (229-4ubuntu10, 229-4ubuntu11), libudev1:i386 (229-4ubuntu10, 229-4ubuntu11), libnm-util2:amd64 (1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.3), libappstream-glib8:amd64 (0.5.13-1ubuntu3, 0.5.13-1ubuntu4), libpostproc-ffmpeg53:amd64 (7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2, 7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), python3-update-manager:amd64 (1:16.04.3, 1:16.04.4), systemd-sysv:amd64 (229-4ubuntu10, 229-4ubuntu11), libpam-systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu10, 229-4ubuntu11), systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu10, 229-4ubuntu11), libswscale-ffmpeg3:amd64 (7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2, 7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libavresample-ffmpeg2:amd64 (7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2, 7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:amd64 (12.10.3+16.04.20160223.1-0ubuntu1, 16.04.1+16.04.20160927-0ubuntu1), libavcodec-ffmpeg56:amd64 (7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2, 7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libavformat-ffmpeg56:amd64 (7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2, 7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), tzdata:amd64 (2016f-0ubuntu0.16.04, 2016g-0ubuntu0.16.04)
End-Date: 2016-10-17  15:21:14
```

Comment: 16.04.3? I don't think that exists.

Comment: Ok, i tought it did because i saw a lot of names ending with that like this one: '1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.3'.

Comment: But i still have this issue on my Dell laptop. Does anybody have any idea where to look or what to try? Or do i need to provide more information? I really hope there is someone how can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working stably after the recent upgrade:

Start-Date: 2016-11-04  16:00:20
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libdns-export162:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.2), dbus-x11:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3, 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1), libisccfg140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.2), libdbus-1-3:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3, 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1), libdbus-1-3:i386 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3, 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1), libcurl3:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.1, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2), mysql-client-5.7:amd64 (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), openjdk-8-jre:amd64 (8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1, 8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2), mysql-server-5.7:amd64 (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libgd3:amd64 (2.1.1-4ubuntu0.16.04.3, 2.1.1-4ubuntu0.16.04.5), libgd3:i386 (2.1.1-4ubuntu0.16.04.3, 2.1.1-4ubuntu0.16.04.5), dbus:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3, 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1), mysql-server:amd64 (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), bind9-host:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.2), dnsutils:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.2), libisc160:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.2), flashplugin-installer:amd64 (11.2.202.637ubuntu0.16.04.1, 11.2.202.643ubuntu0.16.04.1), mysql-client-core-5.7:amd64 (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libisc-export160:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.2), thunderbird-locale-en-us:amd64 (1:45.3.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 1:45.4.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), firefox-locale-en:amd64 (49.0+build4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 49.0.2+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2), liblwres141:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.2), oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 (1.17.9-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), mysql-common:amd64 (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libmysqlclient20:amd64 (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), thunderbird:amd64 (1:45.3.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 1:45.4.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libdns162:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.2), openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1, 8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2), firefox:amd64 (49.0+build4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 49.0.2+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2), libisccc140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.2), libbind9-140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.2), curl:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.1, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2), thunderbird-locale-en:amd64 (1:45.3.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 1:45.4.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), thunderbird-locale-nl:amd64 (1:45.3.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 1:45.4.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), mysql-server-core-5.7:amd64 (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.1, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2)
End-Date: 2016-11-04  16:01:11